# Arduino Mouse.Click Function (C#)

Tags: c#, arduino

Arduino IDE Codes

```
#include <Mouse.h>
 
byte bt[3];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Mouse.begin();
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.readBytes(bt, 3);
    Mouse.move(bt[0], bt[1], 0);
    Serial.read();
    if(bt[2]==1){
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_MIDDLE);
    }
    if(bt[2]==2){
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_RIGHT);
    }
  }
}
```

C# Codes

```
        public static void ArduinoMove(int xcoord, int ycoord)
        {
            port.Write(GetRealVal(xcoord), 0, 1);
            port.Write(GetRealVal(ycoord), 0, 1);
        }
```

In this case, I can move the mouse using the "ArduinoMove(x, y)" code, but how can I make the mouse left click?

Answer (score 0):

Like shown in the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/mouse/mouseclick/), the Mouse library also allows you to use `MOUSE_LEFT`. So you just can add an additional case for that in your Arduino implementation

```
if (bt[2] == 3)
{
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT);
}
```

which then can be [written](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) like

```
port.Write(new byte[] { 0, 0, 3 } , 0, 3);
```

Note that the first two bytes are set to `0` since they are used to move the mouse in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess by utilizing Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT); something similar to this:

```
void loop(){
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.readBytes(bt, 3);
    Mouse.move(bt[0], bt[1], 0);
    Serial.read();
    if(bt[2]==1){
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_MIDDLE);
    }
    if(bt[2]==2){
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_RIGHT);
    }
    if(bt[2]==3){
    Mouse.click(MOUSE_LEFT);
    }
  }
}
```

I mean, you already use MOUSE_RIGHT and MOUSE_MIDDLE, it's not much of a leap of faith to expect there is also a MOUSE_LEFT available to use, or?

Comment: So how should I call the ArduinoMove function after writing this code?